# Extracting text after last period in string

Tags: regex, r

I realize this question probably seems painfully simple to most regular expression masters, but reviewing similar questions has not yielded a solution.

I have a vector of e-mail addresses called `email` and would like to extract the text after the final period in each one.  For the sake of example,

```
email<-c("xxxxx1@xxx.com", "xxxx2@xxx.edu", "xxxxx3@xxx.co.uk")
```

I have tried:

```
grep("[\.][a-zA-Z]*?$", email, value=T)
```

This gets me the error message:

> Error: '.' is an unrecognised escape in character string starting ""."`

Removing the escape character on the other hand

```
grep("[.][a-zA-Z]*?$", email, value=T)
```

returns the entire e-mail address as does:

```
grep("\\.[a-zA-Z]*$", email, perl=T, value=T)
```

I'd really appreciate help at this point.

Comment: Can you show some example to test?

Comment: Like an example email address?  Try `xxx@xxxx.com`   Ideally the solution would just yield `.com`

Comment: You need to use `gsub` or `sub` instead of `grep`i.e. `sub('.*\\.', '', email)`

Comment: `str_extract(a, "[^.]*$")`

Comment: Thanks Akrun and Avinash, those both work perfectly.

Comment: `tools::file_ext(email) `

Answer (score 26):

If you need to extract the string after the last period (`.`), try with `sub`

```
sub('.*\\.', '', email)
#[1] "com" "com"
```

#### data

```
email <- c('akrun.123@gmail.com', 'xxx$xxxx.com')
```

Comment: looking now, I prefer your answer! also going to add that file_ext uses a slightly different approach: https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/d28b1e480fed4e00ea85f61becb73527bd6e7c7f/src/library/tools/R/utils.R#L23

Answer (score 12):

Try

```
email <- c("michael.chirico@some.isp.com", "xxx@xxxx.com")
sapply(strsplit(email, split= ".", fixed = TRUE), tail, 1L)

# [1] "com" "com"
```

---

Also, as pointed out by @RichardScriven, `tools` has a tailor-made function for what you're trying to do specifically:

```
library(tools)
file_ext(email)
# [1] "com" "com"
```