# In R, how can I manipulate variable in dataframe using regular expression?

Tags: regex, r

This is the dataset

```
df1 <- data.frame("id" = c("ebi.ac.uk:MIAMExpress:Reporter:A-MEXP-503.100044", 
                       "ebi.ac.uk:MIAMExpress:Reporter:A-MEXP-783.100435",
                       "ebi.ac.uk:MIAMExpress:Reporter:C-DEA-783.100435"),
              "Name" = c("ABC", "DEF", ""))
```

The product of the dataset

```
                                                  id   Name
1   ebi.ac.uk:MIAMExpress:Reporter:A-MEXP-503.100044    ABC
2   ebi.ac.uk:MIAMExpress:Reporter:A-MEXP-503.100435    DEF
3   ebi.ac.uk:MIAMExpress:Reporter:A-MEXP-503.100488
```

I want to make the dataframe look like this

```
       id     Name
1  100044      ABC
2  100435      DEF
3  100488       NA
```

Can anyone show me how to approach this problem?

Comment: In this case you should be able to just get the substring. For instance by using `substr` or maybe by the faster `strsplit` on `.`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regex way to find the last dot:

```
df1$id <- as.character(df1$id)
regexpr("\\.[^\\.]*$", df1$id) # may not need \\ on second one
```

or `sapply(gregexpr("\\.", x), tail, 1)`

Easier to remember, non-regex way:

```
df1$id <- as.character(df1$id)

df1$id <- sapply(strsplit(df1$id,split="\\."),tail,1)
df1$Name[df1$Name == ""] <- NA

df1
```

> ```
>       id Name
> 1 100044  ABC
> 2 100435  DEF
> 3 100435 <NA>
> ```

`sapply(strsplit(df1$id,split="\\."),tail,1)` is from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31774086/extracting-text-after-last-period-in-string-in-r).

Comment: You do not need the double escapes before a period within a character-class sub-expression. (They are not "meta" within the character-class evaluation environment. see `$regex`).  I find it easier to specify a period-character in a pattern by just enclosing in square-brackets, so this could just be `"[.][^.]*$"`