# How to move specific data from one column to another using r

Tags: r, regex

Im having a problem trying to move data from my address column to my postal code column. 
For example:

[image]

On the second line im trying to take "Dublin 22" from the data.Address column and moving it to the data.Postal.Code column.

Im using R but i have no idea how to implement it.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please update your question and show several example addresses and where the postal code appears.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please have a read at [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and of course how to [make a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). In addition, please add expected output as well as the code you have tried and failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
data.Postal.Code <- gsub("^.*, (.*)$", "\\1", data.Address)
```

**Update:**

If you want to move `Dublin 22` to the postal code column whenever it appears in the address then you can try the following:

```
data.Postal.Code[grepl("^.* Dublin 22$", data.Address)] <- "Dublin 22"
```

Here is a demo of the regex used:

## Regex101

Comment: You need to restrict it to `data.Postal.Code[data.Postal.Code == '']`

Comment: @Sotos I interpreted his diagram as being a work in progress, but let me add this possible caviat.

Comment: Actually, the blank entries could even be NA, we really don't know.

Comment: Yeah, I was going to dupe it [with this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31774086/extracting-text-after-last-period-in-string-in-r) but wasn't sure

Comment: Thanks Tim,That piece of code is inserting "Dublin 22" to every empty field in data.Postal.Code whereas i only want every row that has "Dublin 22" in the data.Address column to be moved to the data.Postal.Code column and so on.

Comment: @SeanMcDermott I updated my answer and hopefully this is what you have in mind.

Comment: Works perfect, appreciate it Tim.